# What is the proper way of selecting multiple scalars within the same "using" statement with Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, async-await, dapper

I have wrote the following method, which I hoped to make the method run faster by executing the tasks in parallel:

```
public static async Task<ExampleData> GetExampleDataAsync()
    {       
        try
        {
            var data = new ExampleData();
            
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
            {
                //Do them in parallel
                var Task1 = connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>
                    ($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ExampleTable)");

                var Task2 = connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>
                    ($"Select Count(*) from dbo.ExampleTable where(row1 is null)");

                var Task3 = connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<double>
                    ($"Select SUM(row2) from dbo.ExampleTable");

                await Task.WhenAll(Task1, Task2, Task3);

                data.prop1 = await Task1;
                data.prop2 = await Task2;
                data.prop3 = await Task3;
            }

            return data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }         
    }
```

Unfortunately, I receive the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'BeginExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is connecting.'

How should I implement it correctly?

Comment: do you expect performance improvement by such syntax, or you want cleaner(or less) code?

Comment: I would like to replace data.prop1 = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync...;  data.prop2 = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync... ;  data.prop3 = await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync...; with this code, so that instead of waiting for each selection in sequence, it executes them at the same time, and waits until all of them are complete.

Comment: what about wrap each query in their own `using (SqlConnection connection = new ` in a method, and that must work.

Comment: Would that be possible to use lambda expressions? I have many more of these queries, therefore creating a new method for each would clutter the code.

Comment: the method can take the sql string as parameter

Comment: True! Also I guess I can make it a generic method for the return parameter, which changes between int and double.

Comment: Why dont you query all values within a single statement, why does it even have to be seperate queries? If you care for performance, doing 3 table scans is your biggest concern here.

Comment: Do you mean using QueryMultiple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, **executing many commands in parallel against a database will not necessarily be faster**, because you put more load on the server and make it try to serve everything at once, which can just cause each query to block the other.

It's also very difficult to do so on a single connection (unless you use MARS, itself inadvisable), so you would need multiple connections.

In any case, **you shouldn't do multiple queries here at all**. You can get all the information in one shot with one query, and the performance will be the same as executing just one of them. This is because they all select from the same table.

> Note also that the `catch` block is redundant, and that you can use Dapper to retrieve multiple columns directly into your object.

```cs
public static async Task<ExampleData> GetExampleDataAsync()
{       
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<ExampleData>(@"
SELECT
    prop1 = COUNT(*),
    prop2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN row1 IS NULL THEN 1 END),
    prop3 = SUM(row2)
FROM dbo.ExampleTable;
        ");
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `MARS` can you give link?

Comment: if the user handles the exception message in `catch` block, is it still redundant?

Comment: @LeiYang https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets And this particular `catch` block only had `throw;` in it

Comment: I had to do something like this in a similar situation 'Select @@Round As Round, @@PlayerCount As PlayerCount, @@Remainder As Remainder'

Comment: Something like what? Retrieving multiple columns is pretty normal, as is conditional aggregation. `@@` is not valid unless it refers to a system function. So I'm not sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to wrap each query in separate `SqlConnection`. So your code would look like this:

```
public async Task<int> FooMethod_1()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)
    {           
        return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>
            ($"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ExampleTable)");
    }
}
```

and then just `await` this methods:

```
var task1 = FooMethod_1();
// other tasks...
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

In addition, it is possible to use generic version:

```
public async Task<T> FooMethod_1<T>(string sqlCode)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)                  
        return await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(sqlCode);     
}
```

Comment: There are two small typos in your solution: QueryAsync should be awaited and the generic method should be: public async static Task<T> FooMethod_1<T>(string sqlCode)

Comment: @BalazsSzekeres thanks for correction! :) Feel free to edit my reply, if your edits will be permitted, then you will be given additional points to your reputation!